# Unable to solve the error after installing virtualenv

Tags: python, python-3.x, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

My computer system is mac OS ventura 13.4. After I install virtualenv and virtualenvwrapper using pip3, a large error message pops up every time I open the terminal
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CkXH1.jpg)

Can you please help me to see how to solve this problem

Comment: Did you do anything else other than just running pip? If so, any line of code you may have copy-pasted had "--version" on it?

Comment: Added a few lines of configuration to .zshrc

Comment: export WORKON_HOME=~/workspaces
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python3
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it happens when you open the terminal, then it means stuff added to `.bashrc` (or whatever your shell's config) or `.profile` is messed up and contains (directly or via `source`) some call to `virtualenv --version#` (with the #, yes, the error says so).

So first thing would be to check those two files and find whether any of them calls that directly. And if yes, just remove that line - save, source or open new console and see if the help (with error) pops up again or not.

[Note: Installation itself shouldn't have made you edit virtualenvwrapper.sh itself, but if you did open it and modified it, even accidentally, please do tell. That would mean the breaking line could be there. See below - [1].]

Then walk through virtualenvwrapper's installation steps again to see whether your .bashrc/.profile/whatever shell you're using config is correct - https://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html#basic-installation

---

If you don't have that call directly, you'd want to inspect all `source` calls in those files.

Is there anything suspicious like call to your own file? If yes, first check that file.

[1] Virtualenvwrapper's installation itself should've made you add `source` with path to `virtualenvwrapper.sh`. There shouldn't have been any modifications to that file on your part. Please just make sure the file is the same as https://github.com/python-virtualenvwrapper/virtualenvwrapper/blob/main/virtualenvwrapper.sh - no added lines, no missing lines etc.

Comment: OK, i'm going to check, thank you